# Guestbook Plugin or code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap comment form already. All I want is a way to display people's comments in the same page. But I want some really nice looking way of displaying the comment. Is there any plugin that I can use? Or does bootstrap support such a thing?

Your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is intended to be a css-framwork and brings only some simple javascript. You are looking for a script based on php for example. Maybe you should check out this: http://www.inverudio.com/guestbook/
and then change the layout as you want.